# splunk-otel-collector heml chart in terraform

Tags: kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-aws, splunk

Hi i'm trying to install splunk helm chart in terraform but I got this error :

```
 ERROR
 ERROR    Error: failed pre-install: 1 error occurred:                                                                                                                                           
 INFO     "customer_application_allowlist_ips" but a value was found in file                                                                                                                     
 ERROR            * timed out waiting for the condition                                                                                                                                          
 INFO     "/tmp/tmpva3pvz6o.json". If you meant to use this value, add a "variable"                                                                                                              
 ERROR                                                                                                                                                                                           
 INFO     block to the configuration.                                                                                                                                                            
 ERROR                                                                                                                                                                                           
 INFO                                                                                                                                                                                            
 INFO     To silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide                                                                                                             
 ERROR                                                                                                                                                                                           
 INFO     certain "global" settings to all configurations in your organization. To                                                                                                               
 ERROR      with helm_release.splunk-otel-collector,                                                                                                                                              INFO     reduce the verbosity of these warnings, use the -compact-warnings option.                                                                                                              
 ERROR      on splunk-otel-collector.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "splunk-otel-collector":                                                                                              
INFO                                                                                                                                                                                            
ERROR       1: resource "helm_release" "splunk-otel-collector" {                                                                                                                                
INFO     Warning: Value for undeclared variable                                                                                                                                                 
 ERROR
```

Is there anything I'm missing?